# Default momentjs to dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am setting the locale in momentjs using :

```
moment.locale('en-GB');
```

but every time I create a new object I have to use a format string, e.g.:

```
moment('12/01/2001','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Is it possible for me to default moment so that it uses dd-mm-yyy everywhere so I only have to use:

```
moment('12/01/2001');
```

Comment: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/308

Comment: Per the thread linked by @Andreas' comment, it seems like "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments this seems not to work. You can provide a wrapper function though:

```
function localeMoment(date){
    return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

This is probably the closest that you can get.

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate, but I guess I have no choice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the @k-nut function in a more elegant way

```
String.prototype.toMomentDate = function () {
    return moment(this, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

and call it on your strings which store dates

```
var date = '12/01/2001';
date.toMomentDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`moment('12/01/2001','L');`

"L" will automatically set the current format depend on locale